# Using custom file system with Entity Framework 4.0

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, odata

Is it possible, or even recommended, to use a custom file system with the Entity Framework? I am working on a learning project to see if I can take some custom intermediate files (the majority of them binary files) from an older file system and use the Entity Framework to pass data through a WCF service with OData.

I'm having quite a bit of trouble finding tutorials on how to possibly do this. Would this not be the recommended approach with a custom filesystem? I really like the capability of WCF services and want to take advantage of them for sure. I am not sold on the entity framework, is there a better way to pass this data into a WCF service?

Thank you.

Comment: What does "file system" mean in this context?

Comment: @Gabe physical binary files. Organized folders/file structures.

Comment: You mean you want to use EF to get data out of proprietary files instead of a relational database? Are you going to be writing queries? Doing updates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advise against this. Essentially you want to use EF as a database engine. You need to ensure that your binary files are queryable. And that you have a streaming architecture to avoid doing a total in memory copy of the data.

However if the data is small enough then I would simple create an object model that represents your data and use basic Linq for the interrogation of it.

There is another solution that allows streaming from a text file (Implementing an IEnumerable on your object and use yield from a tokenized file stream.

However I suspect the aim of your problem is to use WCF Data Services to make your life easier, not more complicated. In which case write this idea off and go back to the drawing board, as this is NOT going to be trivial

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why not. EF is designed to work with various data providers. There are open source projects like the [Postgresql provider for EF](http://npgsql.projects.postgresql.org/) that you can study to find out how to do it.